# Google Earth API in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight, google-earth-plugin

I have been handed over a Silverlight 4 application that uses the Google Earth API. We have an issue with newer versions of Google Earth: In Internet Explorer, the map displays as a white background with the text "ATL 10.00". In other browsers, the background is just white (cannot see any text).
It works with Google Earth version 6.0.3.2197 but not in any version after that.

I have read this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-samples/issues/detail?id=699)
- but none of the suggestions there worked. I must note, though, that the JavaScript code for initializing GE in Silverlight is rather complex, but as far as I can se, the initialization of GE is done in the google.setOnLoadCallback function.

It would be nice, if someone knows what exactly the "ATL 10.00" message means.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Please let me know if I should clarify in further detail.

UPDATE:
The problem was caused by 2 things and probably a combination of the two:
1. The container for the map was added dynamically with JavaScript into another div
2. The container's width and height was set to 0 in order to hide the map.

So, the solution for me was to render the containing div together with the rest of the DOM. In order to "hide" the map, I positioned it absolute beyond the bounds of the screen.

Hope this can guide others to solve similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ATL` in referring to the `Active Template Library` in Windows. ATL in Windows is a set of template-based C++ classes that let developers create COM objects (rather like MFC and ActiveX).

`10.00` here simply refers to version of ATL being used. Seeing it probably means that the COM object (GEPlugin in this case) has not been created or initialised properly in the browser. The blank screen with the version number in the centre is what the plugin looks like before it loads content.

So, it is not really an error message at all - indeed one could say it is really the failure of  an error message to appear that you are seeing.

Anyhow, to answer your question in simple terms it means than the version of ATL that was used to create the plugin was version 10.00.

In practical terms it means that the plugin failed to initialise properly for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you by any chance know what could have changed from the version that works to the following versions, where the plugin fails to initialize?

Comment: Really hard to say, I have only ever seen this issue in c# when using old versions of the plugin (pre version 6) when attempting to load the api into a browser control that doesn't have a base url set. Without seeing your code it is impossible to say if it is a bug with the plugin or your code in this case. That said, one change that could be a factor is the later versions of the plugin are more fussy about types - so double check any variables you pass are the expected types (i.e don't pass 1 for true, 0 for false, or a string when a number is expected)